# Can't find images over https

Tags: php, apache, laravel, https

I'm having a question. I'm trying to service my webshop over https (using letsencrypt). I've added the following in my .htaccess file to direct all traffic over https:

```
# All HTTPS to HTTP.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I'm using apache2 on a ubuntu 16.04 server. I have a folder in my root `/domain_files/uploads` which 301's as `/var/www/domain/uploads/`

**Now images are not available anymore over `https`:**
https://www.domain.nl/uploads/profilepictures/MXY6x2r8t4U_facebook_profilepic.jpg

`http`:
http://www.domain.nl/uploads/profilepictures/MXY6x2r8t4U_facebook_profilepic.jpg

Comment: Are there more rewrite rules you're note telling us about? The problem does not seem to be in this one.

Comment: @apokryfos Maybe on the ubuntu server itself? Do you know how I can access it?

Comment: No, the ubuntu server itself does not do that. Neither does apache by default. You should go through any `.htaccess` files in subdirectories as they would override the main one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that I had a different .conf file in my Apache2 specially for https:// connections. I updated the 301 path's and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think following code will be helpful for you. i got the solution using this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This looks more or less to be the same as what OP is doing. is the problem the `^` and `$` missing from their regex?

Comment: I'm gonna try it tonight! Hope it works, I'll let you know!

Comment: Sadly this is not working for me. I don't think it's a .htaccess issue but something like a 301 in my Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you configure SSL perfectly in your server. one another thing you can write RewriteBase / just above the </IfModule>